# webpack split node modules from app

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

My stack:
NodeJS + react +... + gulp + webpack 2.1

When transpiling ES6 to common JS, I want to split my project code in two bundles: one with node modules, the other with my app code only. How to do that without specifying explicitly each module to put into the node-module-bundle.

From [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code), I see no way to specify a directory that should be used as an entry. Does anyone know how to do that?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [webpack-split-by-path](https://github.com/BohdanTkachenko/webpack-split-by-path), their example shows how to split your app into app.js and vendor.js bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Using webpack-4  optimization.splitChunks.chunks = 'all' you can put all your node_modules into a single file called vendors~main.js without defining your dependency explicitly.

Comment: `
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/'),
    filename: '[bundle]-[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[vendor]-[chunkhash].js',
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: { name: 'vendor', chunks: 'all' },
  },
`

Is this the correct way to set this up?  This generates the 2 outputs, but they are `[bundle]-some_hash`.js How to I properly name and reference these?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the CommonsChunkPlugin. In the docs there's a [section for vendor libraries](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#2-explicit-vendor-chunk).

But your config, should look like this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
      vendor: ['jquery', 'moment', 'other modules'],
      app: './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js'
 },
 plugins: [
   new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
     name: 'vendor',
     minChuncks: Infinity
   })
 ]
};
```

Comment: I do use `CommonsChunkPlugin` but, based on your example, I have to define manually alll node modules: `vendor: ['jquery', 'moment', 'other modules']`. I would like to not have to define them manually

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I rushed into answering your question.

Comment: @DamienLeroux  have you got the solution for this?? is there any way to point the nodejs module dependency explicitly??